# A dll can't be found although it is in the same folder

Tags: c#, dllimport

my c# app is working fine in win10.  I moved it into another computer which is also win10. but it is not working now. an error pops up:

> xx_win32.dll can't be loaded.

I am sure that all the files are in the same folder.

xx_win32.dll is prepared in c++ by my friend, I use DllImport in my code and it works fine in my computer. What might be the problem?

I put xx_win32.dll in also system32 folder.
I checked the current directory and it is as expected (in the same folder with all the files)

```
public const string DLL_NAME = "xx_Win32.dll"; 

[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int xxDll_GetSize();
```

> system.io.filenotfoundexception: could not load file or assembly

Comment: Is the DLL a 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) DLL? You will have to build your C# specifically as a 32-bit or 64-bit program ("platform target" in the project build settings), matching the DLL. (If you have both a 32-bit and 64-bit version of the DLL, there are ways to dynamically let your C# program load the correct DLL based on whether the C# program is executed by the .NET runtime as 32-bit or 64-bit process, but lets keep it simple for now...)

Comment: Also check with your friend on what dependencies that DLL has. If they can't answer - stop using that code and write your own.

Comment: I changed ("platform target" in the project build settings) to 32-bit(dll is 32-bit) (it used to be any cpu). still can't solve the problem.

Comment: I have added all dependencies of the dll also. this app is working fine at another pc but still it is not working on that specific pc. error is same system.io.filenotfoundexception: could not load file or assembly

Comment: You have not successfully resolved the dependencies

Comment: I think it is related with the .netframework version or maybe c++ runtime library. Because I installed visual studio to the pc than the app is working now. I am going to learn the exact reason sooner hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in two different ways (both ways worked fine):
1- I installed vs 2017 on the host pc. The app worked good and the error disappeared.
2- I go to the xx_Win32.dll file project (c++), rebuilt it with "use MFC in a static library" option. it works now on any pc.

thank you for your valuable comments.